# Is this a characteristic function? Why (not)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I have recieved a home assignment and the question is if $(1-|t|)e^{-|t|}$ is a characteristic function. If it is a yes, then what distribution does it correspond to?

I was wondering if that is a combination of convex characteristic functions, the Polya theorem sadly does not work. I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Perhaps Bochner's theorem may be of use?

Comment: Maybe, but am having a problem checking the positive definiteness of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a homework problem, I will not give a full answer. The candidate characteristic function is integrable on the real line. Therefore, the candidate distribution has a density that can be computed as the inverse Fourier transform. One gets an expression for a potential density; if it qualifies, then we will also be able to determinate the distribution. If not, we will know that the aforementioned function is not a characteristic function.